# How to check if a user follows another user from a list of users?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a follow system in PHP where users can follow/unfollow other users. So far, when a user follows any other user, the id of both the users are stored in 'follow' table in MYSQL database,

```
u_id | f_id
===========
1    | 2
1    | 3
1    | 5
```

Where `u_id` follows `f_id`

Now when `u_id` 1 performs a search on the website, all the users with matching search query are presented, each having a button so that `u_id` 1 may follow them, but there may be some users that are already followed by `u_id` 1. How do I implement such that those users already followed by `u_id` 1 does not have that follow button?

One way is to check every result if they are followed by `u_id` 1 before presenting the search result, but I guess this will be very slow.

Is there any way so that I can do this in a single MYSQL query?

Comment: `select u_id from [users] where u_id not in (select f_id from follow where u_id = <current_users_id>`

Answer (score 0):

> when u_id = 1 performs a search on the website, all the users with matching search query are presented

Looks like you have some kind of query returning  `user_id` and a suggested user `f_id` to follow. Let assume that is a table `suggestion`

```
SELECT s.f_id, 
       CASE 
           WHEN f.id IS NULL THEN 'ON'
           ELSE 'OFF'
       END as ButtonStatus
FROM [suggestion] s 
LEFT JOIN [follow] f
       ON s.user_id = f.u_id 
      AND s.f_id = f.f_id
WHERE 
    s.user_id = @user_id // Variable from your UI.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.*, f.followingUsersId AS followingUsersId 
FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN (SELECT followingUsersId FROM follow WHERE followerUsersId = '".$_SESSION['userid']."') AS f ON u.usersId = f.followingUsersId 
WHERE u.usersName LIKE '%$searchvalue%' ORDER BY f.followingUsersId DESC, u.usersId DESC;";
```

Worked for me!!